# Java War File Will Not Update in Eclipse with WildFly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse version 2019-03 (4.11.0) and Wildfly 16 on Windows 7 64-bit. I've converted my Java Web Project to a Maven one in Eclipse. The initial configuration and deployment through the wizards works but now anytime I make a change to my code and try to re-deploy I am not seeing the updated code. What I've tried so far(I actually am not sure how to make the re-deployment and assumed that one or a combination of the following would force a re-deployment):

1. Update Project (Alt + F5 and Right-click Project --> Maven --> Update Project)
2. `mvn clean`
3. `mvn install`
4. `mvn clean install`
5. Update Project followed by `mvn clean install`

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>GumboChannel</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>GumboChannel</name>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

EDIT: I updated the question to clarify that I actually am not sure how to re-deploy.

Comment: how exactly you re-deploy the war? are you using some webserver integrated in eclipse, or outside?

Comment: @luca.vercelli I'm actually not sure how to re-deploy. I assumed what I was doing was supposed to re-deploy the war file. I am doing all of my operations in eclipse though. I have my Wildfly container configured in eclipse. Just to see if it made a difference, I tried `mvn clean install` from command line but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, none of the options that you listed above redeploys the application.

- Update Project: modifies the Eclipse project to take changes from pom.xml
- `mvn clean install` (from CLI): runs Maven (outside Eclipse), cleans the target directory, compiles all sources into target directory, packages the .war file, installs it in the local .m2 repository. Usually you don't need this at all, just choose "Build automatically" from the menu.

I imagine you have configured Wildfly in the "Server" view of Eclipse. If you want to redeploy, you should find some kind of "Restart" and/or "Redeploy" command in that view.

Comment: Im having the same issue now, with wildfly 27+, isnt deploying the new changes.

Comment: I think you should file a new question. You should explain exactly what you do and what you expect. Tell if you are deploying your app with Eclipse or with some external maven command.